# How do I insert an image "through" the center of a vector shape in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, gradient, layer-composition

I'm wondering what the best way to insert a photo of someone "through" the center of a vector shape would be in Illustrator CC. I've done this in the past through a variety of shape building techniques, but the gradient I'm using this time is throwing me off. [image: Here is the example of what I'm working with.]

Essentially, I have cropped photos of both people pictured, and I'd like their below-the-waist portion to remain obscured, but I'd like their heads to still carry over the top portion of the shapes (as the man on the left's head is.) I've tried shape building, but then the gradient won't carry fluidly over through each new shape. So essentially, what is the most effective technique for layering elements like this while still keeping the gradient consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with Clipping Masks.  What you basically want to do is draw a path outlining where you want the person to appear, place the picture below your new object, then create the clipping mask.  I'll outline this in more detail below.

Starting out with some random lady I found and a diamond shape with a square below that.

[image]

To begin the creation of this "window" that we want our person to appear in, I first select this Anchor Point.  This will also select the two paths on either side.

[image]

Paste the newly copied Anchor Point in place.

[image]

Giving you this:

[image]

Next, draw a big space where you want your person to appear.  The shape of this area doesn't really matter, just ensure its large enough to accommodate the entire image.

[image]

Make sure that this new shape is on top of your image.

[image]

Then create your Clipping Mask.

[image]

Giving you this:

[image]

You can move the image around, within the window, by selecting it in the Layers Palette.

[image]

You may need to make the window bigger, to allow for more movement.  If you do, just move the anchor points on the Clipping Mask path - it behaves the same as any other path.

[image]